# Why does client inside the function has an error?

Tags: python, function, telegram

I have a code

```
   def what(x):
     x = sheet['A1'].value
     client.send_message('me', x)
```

And an error: **RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'WorkerThread1'.**

I can't use client.send_message because of the error

Comment: I tried using client.send_message outside the function but the it says name x is not defined

Comment: Here x is a value from excel

Comment: In order to get a quickly response it would be good to add more context in your question, such as the documentation you are following, more code snippets, etc. Take a look at this documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask